# Refresh game scene in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hey folks I've being working around as follows. I get 2 layers, one's for control and the other's for game stuff. The problem is that the game's stucked ( the game's scene is refreshed and showed but it's out of control) when I trigerred a function for restart from my control layer. Have no idea where the problem is.

```
//restart function from input layer

......

-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {......}
    return self;
}

......

-(void)restart
{
    GameScene* game = [GameScene sharedGameScene];
    [game restartScene];
}

//gameLayer

......

static GameScene* instanceOfGameScene;

@implementation GameScene

+(GameScene*) sharedGameScene
{
    if(instanceOfGameScene == nil)
        instanceOfGameScene = [[self alloc]init];
    return instanceOfGameScene;
}

+(id) scene
{   
    CCScene* scene = [CCScene node];
    GameScene* layer = [GameScene node];
    [scene addChild:layer z:0];

    InputLayer* inputLayer = [InputLayer node];
    [scene addChild:inputLayer z:1];
    return scene;
}

-(void) restartScene
{
    CCScene * newScene = [GameScene scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:\
                 [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.7f scene:newScene]];
}

......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[scene:newScene]` does not seem to be valid ObjC syntax, does this even compile?

Anyway, you'll want to use `newScene` there and nothing else:

```
-(void) restartScene
{
    CCScene * newScene = [GameScene scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:newScene];
}
```

Comment: Oh, Sry for my bad type. I've changed the code above. It should be '[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.7f scene:newScene]]' .

Comment: okay, then maybe you either call restartScene continuously (would explain the "getting stuck" issue) or the previous scene did not dealloc or perhaps the app simply crashed but for whatever reason Xcode did not enter foreground to display the error

Comment: i figured out that the game stucks becoz the gamelayer keeps calling its init(). The instanceOfGameScene from gamelayer somehow turns to be null, but i've no idea why. Everything works fine when i put everything into one layer, but i don't think it's recommended.